# Images not displaying in browser with intellij

Tags: image, jsp, spring-boot, intellij-idea, jpeg

Using springboot,intellij,maven,tomcat-embed-jasper to create a webapp. I want to render image which is placed within the project to be rendered in website. Below is my code.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class EproApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EproApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

welcome.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="webjars/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="webjars/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="webjars/jquery/3.3.1-1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <%@ include file="/WEB-INF/views/js/welcomejs.jsp" %>
    <%@ include file="/WEB-INF/views/css/welcomecss.jsp" %>

    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<img src="../../WEB-INF/views/images/download.jpg" alt="Smiley face" >
<img src="../views/images/download.jpg" alt="Smiley face" >
<img src="../resources/images/download.jpg" alt="Smiley face" >

<button class="width100 height50 w-100">Bootstrap test</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe give us a little more context. What is wrong with this [mcve] that you need help with?

Comment: value mentioned for src is the location of the image inside the project. if i am specifying the location correctly, the image should display, but it is not displaying. what should i change? is there any tutorial that deals with springboot,intellij idea,jsp, images within the project and img tag.

Comment: 1. [Edit] the question and clarify details there. 2. There very well may be tutorials on this subject; did you try to find any? 3. Have you tried debugging your code? You can inspect the Java runtime behaviour with a debugger or print statements, and even inspect the traffic with browser developer mode if this is accessible via HTTP. 4. What does Intellij IDEA have to do with this?

Comment: In short, tell us what you want to do, show what you tried, tell us what results you get. Show your research.

Comment: Easiest way to debug it would be to right click on the broken images to inspect them (or check properties) and see where is it trying to load it from.

Comment: Intellij totally misguiding. The path in which it shows the error "Cannot resolve controller URL '/css/welcome.css'" seems to be valid and worked.